# Does GHC optimize functions that pattern match against a large number of 0 argument data constructors?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a data type, with hundreds of data constructors:

```
data Goo 
  = Goo001
  | Goo002
  | Goo003
  ...
  | Goo999
```

and I make a function that pattern matches on every one of those constructors:

```
  func :: Goo -> Int
  func Goo001 = 78
  func Goo002 = 93
  func Goo003 = 789
  ...
  func Goo999 = 1
```

Does GHC optimize the different function equations in any way, so that to match `Goo999`, it doesn't have to try to match on all the previous 998 equations?

Or would it be better to make a `Data.Map Goo Int` and make func do a lookup on that map?

Comment: It uses binary search iirc. But a jump table might be better: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/9159

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, that's for matches on numerical types like `Int#`. If you test this case it becomes a Cmm `switch`, which I presume *is* a jump table. According to a comment in your linked thread, this is because the range of possible numerical values is known to be contiguous and there's no chance of it being out of bounds, so a jump table works easily.

Comment: @HTNW: ah, ok. Well bwroga: then it uses a jump table :).

Comment: I have closed this against a Q&A that covers the jump table usage discussed in these comments. Ping me if you think there's something in your question left unaddressed.

Comment: @duplode No problem, that question covers everything I wanted to know